# SQL Server - Predicate and Seek Predicate on the same column

Tags: sql-server, predicate

My table has an non-clustered index: `IX_columnA_columnB`

```
CREATE INDEX IX_columnA_columnB ON table (columnA, columnB)
    INCLUDE (xxx)
```

My query has filter on both `columnA` and `columnB`
On execution plan, the optimizer use `seek predicate` on both them, but I see `columnB` appears again in `predicate`
I don't know this case. Anybody can help? Thanks so much

Comment: for this type of questions, if you post  query used  and execution plan as xml and table definitions .that will be a lot helpfull

Comment: @MartinSmith: could you pls delete my question? I tried to delete it but not success then I updated it. Thanks

Comment: got it, thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query predicate is something like

```
recommend Between 179764 and 26506209 and winlostdate >= '2017-07-12'
```

The index is logically ordered as follows.

```
+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
| recommend | winlostdate | Seek | Residual |
+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
|    179764 | 2000-01-01  |      |          |
|    179764 | 2017-07-12  | Y    | Y        |
|    179765 | 2000-01-01  | Y    | N        |
|    179765 | 2017-07-12  | Y    | Y        |
|  26506209 | 2000-01-01  | Y    | N        |
|  26506209 | 2017-07-12  | Y    | Y        |
|  26506210 | 2000-01-01  |      |          |
+-----------+-------------+------+----------+
```

The seek predicate has a start predicate of `(recommend, winlostdate) >= (179764, '2017-07-12')` and reads the index in order until the end condition is reached and `recommend <= 26506209` is not true.

This is the contiguous range where Seek=Y above.

However that range includes two rows that don't match the predicate over all. These are discarded by the Residual predicate on `winlostdate >= '2017-07-12'`